# Detecting specific form constraint failure in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a field in a Symfony form which contains three constraints.

For one of the three constraints, if validation fails, I want to trigger a popup notice on the form once the page has reloaded. This looks beyond the scope of Twig's `form_errors()` function.

Is there any way of finding out if a specific constraint on a single field has failed in my Twig template? I'm struggling to find a way to access this information right now. (I'm not opposed to passing a flag to the template from my controller if necessary.)

(Might be worth adding that this is a Silex project.)

Comment: Not really understand what you mean, but it seems to me that this article can help:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#static-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can check `form.field.vars.errors` like this:

```
<input type="text" name="msisdn" 
    class="{{ form.msisdn.vars.errors|length ? 'error' : '' }}"  
    value="{{ form.msisdn.vars.value }}" />
```

The actual errors are in an array, you can loop and output them individually like this:

```
<span class="errorMessage">
    {% for error in form.msisdn.vars.errors %}
        {{ error.message }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

Comment: Didn't know the 'if not loop.last', it will be helpful, thanks!